# Angularjs (Typescript) directive link function not firing

Tags: angularjs, typescript, directive

I recently started learning Typescript and I have an issue creating a directive. the factory method is executed, but the link function is not. i don't know if this is a structural problem or something else.

This is my directive:

```
namespace app {
'use strict';

class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective{
    restrict: string = 'A';

    constructor(private $compile: ng.ICompileService, private $templateRequest: ng.ITemplateRequestService, private logger: blocks.logger.Logger) {}

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        var directive = ($compile: ng.ICompileService, $templateRequest: ng.ITemplateRequestService, logger: blocks.logger.Logger) =>new MyDirective($compile, $templateRequest, logger);
        directive.$inject = ['$compile', '$templateRequest', 'logger'];
        return directive;
    }

    link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) => {

        scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',() => {
            //more code ...
        });

        scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', ():void => {
            //more code...
        });
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myDirective', MyDirective.factory);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the () when I add the directive to the module.

Working solution:

```
namespace app {
'use strict';

class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective{
    restrict: string = 'A';

    constructor(private $compile: ng.ICompileService, private $templateRequest: ng.ITemplateRequestService, private logger: blocks.logger.Logger) {}

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        var directive = ($compile: ng.ICompileService, $templateRequest: ng.ITemplateRequestService, logger: blocks.logger.Logger) =>new MyDirective($compile, $templateRequest, logger);
        directive.$inject = ['$compile', '$templateRequest', 'logger'];
        return directive;
    }

    link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) => {

        scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',() => {
            //more code ...
        });

        scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', ():void => {
            //more code...
        });
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myDirective', MyDirective.factory()); //EDITED
}
```